# If statement(text exist in iframe) in Javascript for Iframe not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Hi I am new to this site and trying to get some help on this small problem.

I am trying to see if a set of text (Listing Added) Exists in the iframe then do something with it, if it exists etc.

I have read that there are 2 ways of doing it

1st `$('#my_iframe:contains("I am a simple string")')`

2nd `$('#my_iframe').contents().find().text('my text').length>0`

I tried both and the problem that i have is my if statement does not work. If the text exists or not, it is going to the first condition.

Thanks for your time!

Here is my code

```
<script>        
    $(function(){
        $('#myiframe').load(function(){
        if ($('#myiframe:contains("Listing Added")')){
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "Listing Added!"
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML= "Listing not Added"}
        });
    });       
</script>
```

Comment: 1) If page in iFrame is not from the same origin (protocol, port and url) as the script then forget it 2) you may be too late with the .load since you do not assign the event handler until after the page loaded

Comment: It is from the same domain, it loads the iframe, displays it and goes through that if statement, but it just go to the first conditional but never the second, even if the text Listing Added does not exist.

Comment: Just tried it, , if i remove the $('#myiframe').load(function(){ part,it goes to the first conditional straight away,even if there is nothing in the iframe, if i have the condition in, then it waits for the results, and it goes to the first condition. But never the second condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If page in iFrame is not from the same origin (protocol, port and url) as the script then forget it
2. you may be too late with the .load since you do not assign the event handler until after 
   the page loaded

Assuming the text is in a span

```
$(function() {
  var $container = $("#myiframe").contents().find("span:contains('Listing Added')"),
      added = $container.length>0?" ":" not ";
  $("#result").html("Listing"+added+"Added!");
});
```

But why not

```
 $(function() {
   $.get("mylist.ext",function(data) { // or $.post if needed
     var added = data.indexOf("Listing Added") !=-1;
     $("#result").html("Listing"+(added?" ":" not ")+"Added");
     $("#someContainer").html(data); // instead of iframe
   });
 });
```

Comment: I am trying to wait until the iframe to get result back from a form before i load the iframe. The iframe contains the results, I tried uploading an image but i dont have enough points....anyways the iframe just contain texts inside it, so if the Listing added exist in the iframe, then if statement etc.

Comment: The odd thing is, i can display the results from the iframe, in an iframe. But the if statement isnt working. I tried your edit, if i remove the .load, it loads too early. I just tried combining your code with .load function but its still the same result. Seems like it does not detect the text

Comment: Why use an iframe at all then? Load the thing with Ajax and read the content directly - see update

Comment: Hi，cos i think i might not be able to do it with ajax as i didnt submit the form through ajax，i posted it through a html form

Comment: If you post to the same server as the script, you can use Ajax. Change $.get to $.post if necessary

Comment: Hi yer i am avoiding it cos i have images in the form and i think i might have to make a lot of changes if i use ajax to post the form.i have never tried it before，not so sure. And all the image validation has been done in the php

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. jQuery ajax can serialise the form before you post it. But since you have decided not to show any HTML I have a hard time heloping you

Comment: Hi sorry i am just not at the computer at the moment. I understand what you mean. I just read a few examples on here amd posting images via ajax seems a lot more extra work needed on top of what i have at the momemt. But i will try to figure out the problem

Comment: I managed to fix it, the conditions doesn't like >0, i put >=1 then it works

Comment: That is plain weird since >= 1 is ALSO >0

Comment: I know, it seems like it doesn't like >0 all the rest of the code are the same....

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script >


        $('#myiframe').load(function(){
   if($("#myiframe").contents().text().search("Added")>=1){


         $("#result").html("Listing Added!");
    }
        else{

                   $("#result").html("Listing Not Added!");}

          });


    </script>
```